# Format of the initialization string does not conform to the OLE DB specification

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

I'm getting the following error when trying to read an Excel file using a third-party component

> Format of the initialization string does not conform to the OLE DB specification

Now, I know the words "third party component" are going to set off alarm bells here, but hear me out.

Here's the connection string I'm using

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;
Data Source=C:\users\rory\downloads\testdb_4.xls;
Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;';
```

I've got this *exact* connection string to work no problem with the following C# code

```
using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection())
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    conn.ConnectionString = connstring;
    using (OleDbCommand comm = new OleDbCommand())
    {
        comm.CommandText = "select * from [TEST_DB$]"; 
        // TEST_DB is the name of the sheet
        comm.Connection = conn;
        using (OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter())
        {
            da.SelectCommand = comm;
            da.Fill(dt);
            // do stuff with dt
        }
    }
}
```

This works as expected, and the datatable is filled with data from the Excel file. However when I try to access it from the component, I get the error above.

I'm not an expert on OLE DB, but I was under the impression that the drivers are at the OS level and if they work for one app / connection string they should work for all apps with that same connection string. Am I wrong? And if so, does anyone have a clue what's going on here?

I have contacted support for the component.

Answer (score 3):

The solution to this ended up being to replace the single quotes with escaped doubles.

```
 string conn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" + 
 "Data Source=C:\users\rory\downloads\testdb_4.xls;" + 
 "Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;'"; // single quotes
```

became

```
 string conn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" + 
 "Data Source=C:\users\rory\downloads\testdb_4.xls;" + 
 "Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;\""; // escaped double quotes
```

`OleDbConnection` had no problem with single quotes but apparently some apps and components do.